# Expected value notation

Tags: probability

If someone writes $E(X-Y)^2$ does it mean $E(X^2 - 2XY + Y^2)$ or $E(X-Y)×E(X-Y)$?

For reference, the math problem which contains this notation is

If X and Y are i.i.d with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, what is $E(X-Y)^2$? Providing the question can help me determine what the notation means because maybe only one of the two interpretations of $E(X-Y)^2$ allow me to solve this problem.

Comment: It means the former. Perhaps $E[(X-Y)^2]$ makes it clearer, but the brackets are often omitted when it is clear from context. If it was the latter, you would have been given $[E(X-Y)]^2$.

Comment: For me the notation is not 
unmistakable. Both interpretations a possible.

Comment: The first option.  Note that E is *the* **linear** functional from the space of random variables to $R^n$.

Comment: If someone uses $E(X-Y)^2$ to mean $E(X-Y)\times E(X-Y)$, then it is just lazy notation. I have even seen the somewhat ambiguous $E^2(X-Y)$ to mean $E(X-Y)\times E(X-Y)$ before. Everything depends on context, which is pretty clear in your case.

Comment: Maybe a one line explanation is that expectation is essentially an integral . To be precise, it is the Lebesgue integral of a random variable with respect to the Probability measure. But you can just remember a basic guideline that expectation will satisfy all the properties of an integral . So technically $E(X-Y)^{2}=\int(X-Y)^{2} $

Answer (score 0):

$E(X-Y)^2$ means the former, i.e. $$E\big[(X-Y)^2\big].$$ The brackets are usually omitted for the sake of simplicity. The similar expression $E^2(X-Y)$ can be understood as $E(X-Y)\cdot E(X-Y)$.